# What would cause a parent window to not know that it had a child dialog?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-mobile

In my native windows mobile app I've got a window that creates a dialog.  Lets say my window handle is `hMainWnd`.

I create the dialog using [`DialogBoxParam()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932921.aspx) and passing in `hMainWnd` as the dialog's parent:

```
DialogBoxParam(_,_,hMainWnd,_,_);
```

Let's say the dialog's handle is `hDlgWnd`.  From within the dialog, [`GetParent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921830.aspx) returns `hMainWnd` as expected:

```
//We're inside the dialog created above
HWND hParent = GetParent(hDlgWnd); //hParent == hMainWnd
```

Here's the odd thing, calling [`GetWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa929220.aspx) to find the children of `hMainWnd` returns `NULL`, signifying that it has no children.  I would expect the function to return `hDlgWnd`

```
//We're inside the main window    
HWND hChild = GetWindow(hMainWnd, GW_CHILD); //hChild == NULL
```

How can a child know its parent when the parent doesn't know its child?

Answer (score 3):

`GetWindow` with `GW_CHILD` apparently does not retrieve descendant windows, only child windows. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515.aspx):

> The retrieved handle identifies the
>   child window at the top of the Z
>   order, if the specified window is a
>   parent window; otherwise, the
>   retrieved handle is NULL. The function
>   examines only child windows of the
>   specified window. It does not examine
>   descendant windows

What is the difference between a child and a descendant? I don't know but [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494.aspx) might get you what you need.

Comment: Sorry, WS_CHILD was a typo.  I've fixed it and attempted to clarify the question.  How'd I do?

Answer (score 1):

A Window is either a child window (has WS_CHILD style) or is a top-level window.

Top-level windows have no parent window, but they might have an owner window. Child windows have a parent, but no owner.

The GetParent( ) function return the parent of a child window or the owner of a top-level window. Hence, it is misnamed -- it should be called GetParentOrOwner().

So what is happening is that you are getting the owner of your top-level window from GetParent(), but since it isn't actually the parent, hDlgWnd isn't hMainWnd's child.